# ngx component on bootstrap in Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, angular-material, ngx-bootstrap

I made a modal in angular and I sent the parameters to the modal through BsModalService

but seems it doesn't work

I reviewed my code many times but

this error appears in console :

```
ERROR TypeError: this.modalService.show is not a function
    at q.openRolesModal
```

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YtkN.png)

this component has a button will do this function openRoleModal()

`user management component`

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class=" table tablesorter" id="">
        <thead class=" text-primary">
          <tr>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Active Roles</th>
            <th class=" text-center"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr  *ngFor="let user of users">
            <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{user.roles}}</td>
                <td class="text-center"><button (click)="openRolesModal()" class="btn info">Edit Roles</button></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
```

here i inject modalService as BsModalService and the Modal component as well and then I called this function show but it's give me an error that it's not a function

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService, ModalOptions } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { RolesModalComponent } from 'src/app/modals/roles-modal/roles-modal.component';
import { IUser } from 'src/shared/models/user';
import { AdminService } from '../admin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-management',
  templateUrl: './user-management.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-management.component.scss']
})
export class UserManagementComponent implements OnInit {

 
  users: IUser[] = [];
  bsModalRef:BsModalRef<RolesModalComponent> = new BsModalRef<RolesModalComponent>();

  constructor(private adminService:AdminService,private modalService:BsModalService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsersWithRoles();
  }

  getUsersWithRoles(){
    this.adminService.getUsersWithRoles().subscribe({
      next: users => this.users = users
    })
    
  }

  openRolesModal(){
    const initialState: ModalOptions = {
      initialState:{
      list: [
        'Do thing'
        ,'Another thing'
        ,'something else'
      ],
      title: 'Test Modal'
    }
  };

    //this.bsModalRef = 
    this.modalService.show(RolesModalComponent,initialState);
    this.bsModalRef.content!.closeBtnName = 'Close';
  }
}
```

Roles Modal Component

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{title}}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="visually-hidden">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ul *ngIf="list.length">
      <li *ngFor="let item of list">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">{{closeBtnName}}</button>
  </div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-roles-modal',
  templateUrl: './roles-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./roles-modal.component.scss']
})
export class RolesModalComponent implements OnInit{
title='';
list:any;
closeBtnName = '';

constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef){

}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

to make a modal by ngx bootstrap in angular but didn't work